# derivative which is not continuous with series

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be differentiable in $(0-\delta,0+\delta)$ but $f'$ is not continious in $(0-\delta,0+\delta)$.
Show there are $x_n, y_n$ s.t.
$\forall n :x_n\neq0, y_n\neq0, x_n\neq y_n $ and $x_n\rightarrow0, y_n\rightarrow0$

doesn't imply that:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n}=f'(0)$

I can see that the function below for example fulfill that but how can I show the above statement for a general function $f$?
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0. 
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The statement as written is ungrammatical and it is unclear exactly how it is intended to be interpreted.  In any case, though, it is not true that a counterexample exists for an arbitrary function $f$ satisfying the hypotheses.  For instance, $f'$ could be continuous at $0$ and discontinuous somewhere else in $(-\delta,\delta)$, and then it would follow easily from the mean value theorem that $\frac{f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n}\to f'(0)$ for any sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ with the stated properties.